# Blender 2.8: Using `parent_type` = `ARMATURE` (instead of the modifier) seems to not deform the mesh in the viewport

Tags: armature, parent

We have a blocking issue preventing us from upgrading to Blender 2.8:

Using `parent_type` = `ARMATURE` (instead of the modifier) seems to *not* deform the mesh in the viewport.

It works fine in renders though.

Changing the `parent_type` to `object` and using the `Armature` modifier solves the issue. However, our custom exporter heavily relies on and only supports the `parent_type` version. So if there's a way to enable the deform preview in the viewport it would safe us a lot of work. Maybe the issue is even a bug?

Comment: It seems that obj.data.update() updates...

Comment: thanks, I will forward you insight to the bug report:  https://developer.blender.org/T69326